# Terawallet(woo-wallet) Button customization

Tags: php, wordpress-plugin-creation, redirection-wordpress-plugin

Please I need help in customizing the where the “wallet top up” button leads to an already made page on my website as I do not make use of a WooCommerce checkout page.

I only have beginner level php skills, so I just tried adding actions to the plugin which did not go well